# How do I parse with respect to char array indices (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, parsing, char

How do I parse a char array such as:

```
"2019-11-01T17:00:10.000Z"
```

I want 17:00:10.000 and nothing else. How do I parse with respect to the char array indices?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem, so far?

Comment: I recommend using `std::string` and `std::string::find`.

Comment: Unrelated to your specific question, but maybe related to a related underlying issue, watch this youtube video about zoned time, a whole library for parsing and using time. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vwd3pduVGKY builds upon the chrono talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M watch the latter if you don't have an understanding of `chrono`.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest and safest way to deal with strings is to use the standard [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). The `std::string` has many class member functions that can help with this. One of them is [`substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) that can be used to create a new `std::string` from a part of a string.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

std::string get_time_str(const std::string& timestamp) {
    if(timestamp.size() != 24) 
        throw std::runtime_error("bad timestamp: "+ timestamp);

    return timestamp.substr(11, 12); // start at pos 11 and 12 chars forward
}

int main() {
    const char* ts = "2019-11-01T17:00:10.000Z";
    std::cout << get_time_str(ts) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
17:00:10.000
```

Comment: Note: If the size of the string and the position of the tokens of interest are not constant, there are [a variety of functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string#Search) you can use to find the position of a particular character like `':'` (a token delimiter)